# Iterated integral vs double integral

Tags: multivariable-calculus

So I'm a little confused about the difference between iterated and double integrals, I did a little bit of looking around on the internet, but I couldn't find anything to answer my question. On Wikipedia, there's something about area vs numerical computation, but it was really hard to understand the article. Could someone please explain this to me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Double integrals are integrals of function of two variables, but Iterated integrals are integral of integral... of single variable function.

Example $$ \iint f(x,y) dx dy $$ is a double integral but $$ \int \Biggr ( \int f(x) dx\Biggl) dx$$ is an iterated integral.

Comment: It is interesting to consider the case where $f$ is constant. The double integral would give you the area of the shape defined by the integral range, while the iterated integral represents the distance travelled by an object under the force $f$, in the specified time period